# Passing more than one variable to PoolExecutor

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, threadpool

The below code is working but...

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as PoolExecutor

date = "2020-06-12"
adjusted_symbol_list = ["AAPL", "MSFT", "NFLX"]
date_variable = get_specific_date_from_web()


def filter_2ndconfirm(symbol):
    if date == "2020-06-12":
        if make_calc() == True:
            print(symbol)

def filter_2ndconfirm_workers(filter_2ndconfirm_workers, adjusted_symbol_list):
    with PoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        for _ in executor.map(filter_2ndconfirm_workers, adjusted_symbol_list):
            pass

filter_2ndconfirm_workers(filter_2ndconfirm, adjusted_symbol_list)
```

get_specific_date_from_web() is making calculations and grabbing a date after several http connections so should work only once. The above code is working but how can I insert another variable, I mean date_variable into filter_2ndconfirm func? I can make it like below but I don't want to query web for every symbol:

```
def filter_2ndconfirm(symbol):
    date_variable = get_specific_date_from_web()
    if date == date_variable:
        print(symbol)
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't for get that in Python, any time an API gives you a place to stash or pass _one_ opaque value, you can always provide a tuple, or a list, or a dict, or an instance of a custom class, or etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already defined your variable **date_variable** outside **filter_2ndconfirm** func, then you can access its value inside of the function, thus:

```
def filter_2ndconfirm(symbol):
    if date == date_variable:
        print(symbol)
```

However, this way you would not be able to change its value inside of the function. To do so you could use it as a **global** variable.

Otherwise, you can pass **date_variable** as an argument to the function:

Add this new argument to the **filter_2ndconfirm**

```
def filter_2ndconfirm(symbol, date_variable):
    if date == date_variable:
        print(symbol)
    if date == "2020-06-12":
        if make_calc() == True:
            print(symbol)
```

And then add an additional argument to the **executer.map**

```
for _ in executor.map(filter_2ndconfirm_workers, adjusted_symbol_list, date_variable):
```

The second option is generally better since every process works with its own copy of **date_variable**, but your choice could depend on different factors such as a size of the variable, and whether you are editing it in the function.

Comment: So I just figured out date_variable should also be a list like adjusted_symbol_list. Thank you Mike